# Apply format style to tinymce

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I'm trying to insert style in my tinymce.
I want to format text in pre tags with class pretyprint.
I managed to add pre tags, but class isn't added. it adds class if i change pre to e.g div

```
{title: 'code', 'inline-block': 'pre', classes: 'prettyprint'},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        {title: 'code', 'block':'pre', classes:'prettyprint linenum'},
```

Comment: Please explain your changes.

Comment: The better question is *why*, not *what*.